# R Change Base Package Function

Tags: r

I had an error with installing R packages (`unable to move temporary file`), but it can be solved by editing `utils:::unpackPkgZip` to increase the time between the unzipping, i.e.

```
trace(utils:::unpackPkgZip, edit = TRUE)
```

and on line 142 I increase

```
Sys.sleep(0.5)
```

to 2.5. My question is if there is a way to do this automatically on startup, or to just change the function altogether, so I do not have to repeat this every session.

I tried to put

```
unlockBinding("unpackPkgZip", getNamespace("utils"))
utils::assignInNamespace("unpackPkgZip", new_fct, "utils", getNamespace("utils")) 
lockBinding("unpackPkgZip", getNamespace("utils"))
```

where `new_fct`is the function with changed value, in my .Rprofile`s `.First()` function, but then I get

```
Error in utils::assignInNamespace("unpackPkgZip", function(pkg, pkgname,  : 
  locked binding of ‘unpackPkgZip’ cannot be changed
```

I think it is because `.First()` executes before `.First.sys()`

**Edit:** I just realized that in `assignInNamespace`itself, it states

```
if (ns_name %in% tools:::.get_standard_package_names()$base) 
  stop("locked binding of ", sQuote(x), " cannot be changed", 
    domain = NA)
```

So I suppose it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify the function itself,
you can let trace execute code at specified lines with its `at` parameter.
Its documentation states:

> When the `at` argument is supplied, it can be a vector of integers referring to the substeps of the body of the function (this only works if the body of the function is enclosed in { ...}). In this case tracer is not called on entry, but instead just before evaluating each of the steps listed in at. (Hint: you don't want to try to count the steps in the printed version of a function; instead, look at as.list(body(f)) to get the numbers associated with the steps in function f.)

Take `cat` as an example:

```
as.list(body(cat))
[[1]]
`{`

[[2]]
if (is.character(file)) if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (substring(file, 
    1L, 1L) == "|") {
    file <- pipe(substring(file, 2L), "w")
    on.exit(close(file))
} else {
    file <- file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w"))
    on.exit(close(file))
}

[[3]]
.Internal(cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append))
```

The default behavior:

```
system.time(cat("I'm fast\n"))
I'm fast  
 user  system elapsed 
  0       0       0
```

Now with injected code:

```
trace(cat, quote(Sys.sleep(2)), at=3L, print=FALSE)

system.time(cat("now I'm slow\n"))
now I'm slow  
 user  system elapsed 
0.008   0.000   2.001
```